# Failed to restore Team Foundation server databases

Tags: sql-server, tfs, database-restore

**Getting errors restoring TFS databases**

I've scheduled the backups of our team foundation server with the Team Foundation Server Administration Console. It takes every night a full backup, and it looks like it really does.

Now disaster occured, our tfs crashed, and i'm setting up a new windows server with tfs 2012. Luckely i've got backups... But.....

Restoring the backups seems not so easy. 
When i restore, I get the following error messages:

> TF401001: The restore operation for database ... failed. Please refer to the logs for more information

I get this for every database (ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB, Tfs_warehouse, tfs_defaultcollection, TFS_configuration).

Looking at the log file:

```
[Info   @09:07:33.420] RESTORE DATABASE [Tfs_Configuration]  FROM DISK = N'\\172.16.46.234\Backup_TeamFS.crashed\Tfs_Configuration_9858508765097608601L.trn' WITH RECOVERY, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10, STOPATMARK = N'TfsMarkTfpt'
[Error  @09:07:33.514] TF401001: The restore operation for database Tfs_Configuration failed. Please refer to the logs for more information 
[Error  @09:07:33.514] 
Exception Message: The database "Tfs_Configuration" does not exist. RESTORE can only create a database when restoring either a full backup or a file backup of the primary file.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (type SqlException)
SQL Exception Class: 16
SQL Exception Number: 3118
SQL Exception Procedure: 
SQL Exception Line Number: 1
SQL Exception Server: TEAMFS
SQL Exception State: 1
SQL Error(s):
SQL Error[1]: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
    Class: 16
    Number: 3013
    Server: TEAMFS
    Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
    State: 1
    Procedure: 
    Line Number: 1

Exception Data Dictionary:
HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
HelpLink.EvtSrc = MSSQLServer
HelpLink.EvtID = 3118
HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
HelpLink.LinkId = 20476


Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.SqlDatabaseBackupRestoreComponent.Execute(String sqlStatement)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.SqlDatabaseRestore.Restore(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.RestoreFactory.RestoreLogs(ActivityContext context, String serverName, String databaseName, String path, List`1 backupChain, Boolean useMarkAtEnd, Int32 minPercent)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.RestoreDatabases.Run(ActivityContext context)
```

But, i'm fully sure i do have a full backup. Looking at log files from the backup:

```
[9/1/2013 10:24:44 PM] [Info] starting full backups
[9/1/2013 10:24:44 PM] [Info] Taking Full Backup server:TEAMFS database:Tfs_Configuration filename:\\172.16.46.234\Backup_TeamFS\Tfs_Configuration_9858508747697505276F.bak
[9/1/2013 10:24:44 PM] [Info] BACKUP DATABASE [Tfs_Configuration] TO DISK = N'\\172.16.46.234\Backup_TeamFS\Tfs_Configuration_9858508747697505276F.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NOSKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
[9/1/2013 10:32:17 PM] [Info] Backup Complete for database Tfs_Configuration
[9/1/2013 10:32:17 PM] [Info] Finished Full Backup server:TEAMFS database:Tfs_Configuration filename:\\172.16.46.234\Backup_TeamFS\Tfs_Configuration_9858508747697505276F.bak
```

**update**
I've only scheduled the backups to make a full backup, not incrementals. Maybe something to do with that?

Answer (score 2):

we have managed to do this so I shall share my experience..

So you have got backups..

Also, you have got a fresh new OS and installation files for TFS (TFS 2013 in our case)

1. Double click installation file.
2. Once installation completes, ideally MSDN tells you to close the windows and then in the TFS CONSOLSE you have to go to scheduled backups to restore which FAILS so below method will help you resolve the problem:

a.  Restore the config and team collections databases via the SQL Management console

b.  Open the TFS management console

c.  Click on Application Tier and Configure this feature

d.  Run CMD as administrator and run following command:
TFSConfig Accounts /add /AccountType:ApplicationTier /Account:"NT Authority\Network Service" SQLInstance:ServerName /DatabaseName:TFS_Configuration

e.  Then just follow the next button in the tool from step c.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I just walk around this issue. Use your SQL management tool to restore the backup file. They are just like regular Database backup files, so you just treat them like ones.

After you finish, you can see your collections in your TFS console.

You might bump into some errors during the process.

The one I got was missing one collection. You need to restore everything before going to TFS console.

BTW, after you finish, reboot your TFS service or the whole server, otherwise you might bump into another error like can't find the object reference.

Check out this [blog](http://howtoscript.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-restore-tfs-databases-on-another.html) to find some help.

BTW, I assume the reason you did this because you tried to restore TFS to a different server.

You need to reinstall the application tier only from TFS installation. It took me forever to figure it out.